# SwiftUI Image won't update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, swiftui

I'm really new to swift. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the image updating when pressing it? I couldn't find anything about state listeners.

This is the View that bundles two views:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FoodContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            imageView.gesture(tap)
            FoodContentTextView().position(x: bodyWidth/3, y: bodyHeight/2)
        }
    }
}

var imageView = FoodContentImageView(selectedImage: "CheeseBurger")

let tap = TapGesture()
.onEnded { _ in
    if imageView.imageSelected == "Burger" {
        imageView.imageSelected = "CheeseBurger"
        print(imageView.imageSelected)
    } else {
        imageView.imageSelected = "Burger"
        print(imageView.imageSelected)
    }
}
```

And this is the View where the image gets defined:

```
struct FoodContentImageView: View {

    var imageSelected: String

    init(selectedImage: String){
        imageSelected = selectedImage
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(imageSelected).resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center).scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making it very complicated unnecessarily. `FoodContentImageView` just needs to know the name of the image:

```
struct FoodContentImageView: View {

    var imageName: String

    var body: some View {
        Image(imageName).resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center).scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

And you just need to pass in the name. If you store it as a `@State`, it will automatically updates on any change:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text = "CheeseBurger"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FoodContentImageView(imageName: text)
                .onTapGesture {
                    if self.text == "Burger" {
                        self.text = "CheeseBurger"
                    } else {
                        self.text = "Burger"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And there is no need to reference the `imageView` and `tapGesture` at all.

Comment: You are my hero